# Entity Framework Query based on relationship

Tags: entity-framework

If you have database tables with relationships as follows:

**Person**

PersonId (PK), Name

**PersonDoesService**

PersonId (FK), ServiceId (FK)

**Service**

ServiceId (PK), Type

Is it possible with Entity Framework in one statement to get all Persons that does one service based on serviceId?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have  you tried?

Comment: I've tried but dont know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will do what you are asking.  Make sure that your ServiceId exists.

```
var people = context.Service.First(s => s.ServiceId == theServiceIdIWant).Person // IEnumerable<Person>
```